# Xamarin - How to stop SwipeView from moving when swiping a nested swipeable element?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, swipe

I have a `SwipeView` in my Xamarin forms project with a `ListView` inside it with this rough code:

```
<SwipeView Margin="0,0, 0, 0" Padding="0" x:Name="MainSwipeView" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       SwipeStarted="SwipeStarted" SwipeEnded="SwipeEnded" SwipeChanging="SwipeChanging" CloseRequested="SideMenuClosed" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Rotation="180">

    <Grid x:Name="swipeContent" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                

        <ListView x:Name="reportsList" HasUnevenRows="True" Footer="" SeparatorColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               CachingStrategy="RetainElement" ItemsSource="{Binding AllReports}" Margin="20" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsEmptyReports, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolConverter}}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                                
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Clicked="OnRename"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                    Text="Rename"  />
                            <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                    Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                             Remaining view content

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

    <SwipeView.LeftItems VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                        
         Menu code here


    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
</SwipeView>
```

The Swipeview's `LeftItems` are actually on the right hand side in the app because I rotated the  view by 180 degrees (This was to fix a bug and is not relevant to this question). This means that swiping to the left will reveal the items on the right.

This works fine in Android, but in IOS, the `ContextActions` for the `ViewCell` element involve a scrollable menu. This means when I try and scroll to the left inside the `ListView` elements to get the Menu buttons, the swipe view starts to move to the left too, leading to the below screenshot happening.

[image]

Is there a way to stop this from happening, so that whenever I'm swiping inside one of the `ListView` elements, the `SwipeView` doesn't move like this?

[image]

I've been exploring the following ideas but haven't been able to get any to work yet:

1. Using a TouchEffect to fire an event when the finger is down on the list view to cancel the swipe view swipe (There doesn't seem to be a method or property to just cancel a swipe on the swipeview).
2. Making the SwipeView non-swipeable when the finger touches the list view (There doesn't seem to be a way to do this apart from setting `IsEnabled = false;` but that doesn't stop the initial swipe from happening and disables everything inside the swipeview including the `ListView` element).

Comment: Hi, could you share a gif here to explain the wanted effect? From the shared screenshot, will not understand what the needed effect is. And the design of swipeview that contain a Listview is strange.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've updated my original question to include the GIFs. I have implemented the SwipeView in this way to use as a slide-in main menu which means that all of my app page content is contained within the SwipeView.

Comment: Okey, thanks for updating. Because `ContextActions` and `SwipeAction` both need to swip in iOS, there will be some conflicts for application to detect them. I will check thaas wit, if good idea update here.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT sorry what did you mean by your last message? I think you had a typo in it.

Comment: Oh, you are right. That's a typo in it. I mean that will research it, if good ideas will update here.